# setup iOS8 development with Rad studio XE6

Tags: xcode, delphi, ios8, xcode6, delphi-xe6

i'm having some problems building a out of the box mobile project.

i get a compile error where it seems that `/usr/lib/libextentions.dylib` does not exist for the Arm 7 platform.

my setup is:

XE6
XCode 6.0.1
iOS8 SDK
iOS8 mobile phone

i have followed the guides on the matter (with some modification due to Xcode 6).

any suggestions on how to move forward?

Best Regards

Comment: it seems that there is a hotfix that removes the libextentions error http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30013 even though its not not listet
i now has a profiling error... sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Remy said... iOS8 isn't supported. Available to Embarcadero customers is a XE7 PA Server hotfix if you have Xcode 6 installed... If XE7 isn't an option, and/or you are on the trial then my best suggestion would be to uninstall XCode 6 and install XCode 5.1.1 ( or install both and point command line tools to 5.1.1 ). Either option, you can not make use of the iOS8 SDK, you have to use the 7.1 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

XE6 does not support iOS 8 development.  Even the recently released XE7 does not, either.  There are some dependency changes in iOS 8 that the IDE/RTL do not handle yet. However, support for iOS 8 is currently being worked on, so it may be available in an XE7 Update Pack.